# noticed strange behavior, not sure if it using coroutineScope incorrectly

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, withtimeoutornull

Having a list of the data processors.  Each data processor has its own `dpProcess()` which returns true if the process successfully done.

all of the `processor.dpProcess()`  run in parallel with others (via the launch builder).

but only after all data porcessors are completed then the final  `onAllDataProcessed()`  should be called.
This is achived by the coroutineScope {} block.

and also the coroutineScope {} block is controled by the `withTimeoutOrNull(2000)`, so that if the processing of data is not completed in 2 sec then will abort it

```
    suspend fun processData(): Boolean {
        var allDone = dataProcesserList.size > 0
        val result = withTimeoutOrNull(2000) {  // should timeout at 2000
            coroutineScope {  // block the execution sequence until all sub coroutines are completes
                for (processor in dataProcesserList) {
                    launch { // launch each individual process in parallel
                        allDone = allDone && processor.dpProcess()  // update the global final allDone,   if anyone returns false it should be return false 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * strange:  one of the processor.dpProcess() has return false,  but the allDone at here still shows true (and it is not timed out)
         */

        if (result != null && allDone) { // not timeout and all process completed successfully
            onAllDataProcessed()
        } else {
            allDone = false  // timeout or some process failed
        }
        return allDone
    }
```

Noticed a strange behavior and happens more on device of Android 7.1.1 device than others

Some time the final allDone is true even one of the `processor.dpProcess()`  returns false and not timed out.
But same case sometime returns false as expected

Is it because that how it is coded which brings this behavior?

What is better way to put a few functions to run in parallel and wait until all of them are done then advanced to next step. 
And the whole process should timeout and abort

Answer (score 0):

the

```
launch { // launch each individual process in parallel
                        allDone = allDone && processor.dpProcess()  // update the global final allDone,   if anyone returns false it should be return false 
                    }
```

is the problem that `launch` actually could considered to run the block in different thread, so there is concurrence accessing the global allDone, one may have read it before other update it.